# Python Friendly Form

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

The 'friendly form' of a number is written as a sum of reciprocals of distinct positive integers. eg. $$\frac{4}{5} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{20}$$

I have written a python program that calculates the friendly form of an inputted fraction.

```
import math
from fractions import Fraction

def decompose(x):
    if x.numerator == 1:
        return [x]

    # Finds the largest fraction m = 1/p which is less than or equal to x
    m = Fraction(1, math.ceil(float(1 / x)))
    x = x - m

    #Recursively returns a chain of fractions
    return decompose(x) + [m]

def main():
    inp = input("Enter positive fraction in form \"a/b\": ")

    try:
        x = Fraction(inp)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input.")
        return

    if float(x) == 0:
        print("Enter non-zero value.")
        return

    if float(x) < 0:
        print("Converting to positive value.")
        x = -x

    if float(x) >= 1:
        print("Enter valid fraction")
        return

    answer = decompose(x)
    for a in answer:
        print(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Overall, the code is very good, but a few tiny improvements can be made:

- In the decompose function `x = x - m` can be replaced with `x -= m`
- Instead of `return decompose(x) + [m]` and such, use `yield`
- Instead of `for a in answer ...`, use `print(*answer, sep='\n')`
- In the decompose function, `math.ceil(float(1 / x))` can be changed to `math.ceil(1 / x)`. **Python 3.x** automatically interprets `/` as a float operator
- As only `math.ceil` is used, you could just do `from math import ceil`

Here's the final code:

```
from math import ceil
from fractions import Fraction

def decompose(x):
    if x.numerator == 1:
        yield x
        return 

    m = Fraction(1, ceil(1 / x))
    x -= m

    yield m
    yield from decompose(x)

def main():
    inp = input("Enter positive fraction in form 'a/b': ")

    try:
        x = Fraction(inp)

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input.")
        return

    if float(x) == 0:
        print("Enter non-zero value.")
        return

    if float(x) < 0:
        print("Converting to positive value.")
        x = -x

    if float(x) >= 1:
        print("Enter valid fraction")
        return

    print(*decompose(x), sep='\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Every recursive algorithm can be rewritten without recursion. In worst case, using one stack.

I'm not a pythonist, so instead I will write in pseudocode:

```
def decompose(x)
    result = []
    while x.numerator != 1:
        m = Fraction(1, ceil(1/x))
        x -= m
        result.append(m)

    result.append(x)
    return result
```

Now using yield as suggested by @Srivaths it gets simpler:

```
def decompose(x)
    while x.numerator != 1:
        m = Fraction(1, ceil(1/x))
        x -= m
        yield m

    yield x
```